# Unable to create REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND materialized view

Tags: oracle11g

I have two database HB and DSHB. I am trying to create REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND materialized view in DSHB schema wherein HB is remote schema using dblink with following code,

```
CREATE materialized view MV_HB_SYSTEM
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON DEMAND
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS 
SELECT DELETED, SYS_NO FROM HB.HB_SYSTEM@HBLINK;
```

But getting following error in creation,

```
SQL Error: ORA-12018: following error encountered during code generation for "HB"."MV_HB_SYSTEM"
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But on running query " SELECT DELETED, SYS_NO FROM HB.HB_SYSTEM@HBLINK;" in separate connection works perfectly.

I have also created Materialized View Log with following code,
CREATE Materialized View Log ON  HB_SYSTEM;

I have found in some forum that SELECT privilege on Materialized View Log needs to be granted as mentioned below,

```
GRANT SELECT ON MLOG$_<tableName> to DSHB;
```

where DSHB is the account that will accessing the log (ie via the db link).

But when i run this command from HB schema i am getting error stating DSHB user or role is unavailable in HB and i am unable to grant SELECT on Materialized View Log in HB schema. Is it possible to directly grant SELECT privilege to dblink from remote schema? i mean something like below query from HB schema. I tried but didnt work.

```
GRANT SELECT ON MLOG$_<tableName> to HB.HB_SYSTEM@HBLINK;
```

Please suggest how to resolve ORA-00942 error and create REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND materialized view.

Comment: Do you actually have two databases, or two schema in the same database? Which remote user does your DB link connect as?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, yes we have two dbs say(db11, db12). db11 has schema HB and db12 has schema DSHB. db12(schema DSHB) is local and db11(schema HB) is remote. We have created dblink named (HB.HB_SYSTEM@HBLINK) in db12(DSHB schema) to fetch data from HB_SYSTEM table of db11(schema HB).